# Regex to ignore specific symbols together

Tags: html-parsing, python-re

Hello I am doing this problem using RE and the task is to extract the information of a make-up HTML. Title and content is what I need. This is what I came up with so far.

`<body>([^<]*)(?:<[^>]*+>)*([^<]*)(?:<[^>]*+>)*([^<]*)(?:<[^>]*+>)*([^<]*)(?:<[^>]*+>)*<\/body>`

I know its just repeating the same RE but I couldn't match it otherwise, so please help me there as well.
Title being in the `<title> </title>` and content being in `<body> </body>`. But there is a problem. I need to ignore all the `/n` in the text and get only the text.

this is some sample text :
`<html>\n<head><title>Some title</title></head>\n<body>Here<p> is some </p>content <a href="www.somesite.com">\nclick</body>\n</html>`

also I know that I should not parse HTML with RE from here [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454), but my task requires me to use RE.